# Accessing numerical json keys by its "names" in AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs, key

My JSON file contains clothing sizes and their stock quantities.

```
[{"46":0},{"48":0},{"50":0},{"52":0},{"54":0},{"56":0},{"58":0},{"60":0},{"94":0},{"98":0},{"102":0},{"106":0},{"110":0},{"24":0},{"25":0},{"26":0},{"27":0},{"28":0}]
```

I am trying to print the size name like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="(size, stock) in sizes">
    {{ size }}
</li>
```

All it shows me is a list of 0 through 17. Is there a way to print the size name without having to add a letter to the key?

Comment: Is it possible to turn your JSON response to this format

{"46":0, "48":0,"50":0,"52":0,"54":0,"56":0,"58":0,"60":0,"94":0,"98":0,"102":0}

Comment: Really, you should change your model to something like [{size: 46, stock: 0}, {size: 48, stock: 0}, ...]. What you have there is unusable.

Comment: Since your are using key-value iteration on an array your variable names are misleading. What you get is `(index, obj) in sizes`. Do what JB Nizet suggested above.

Comment: Do you expect this http://plnkr.co/edit/jVipdTPBEKBLsq4yIGT6?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not about the key. The problem is that you're iterating over array of objects, and keys would be `0-17` and values would be the objects like: `{"46":0}`.

If you can modify the JSON, the modify it like that:

```
[ { size: 46, quantity: 10 }, { size: 47, quantity: 11 }, ... ]
```

Then you can refer to sizes and quantities like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="sizeEntity in sizes">
  {{ sizeEntity.size }}: {{ sizeEntity.quantity }}
</li>
```

Hope that hepls.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
<ul ng-repeat="size in sizes">
    <li ng-repeat="(size, stock) in size">
    {{size}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/39Dng8yukYnkscxLZ35i?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

you can have repeat on repeat. checkout this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/XJTHnIOld8n36sUixFhQ?p=preview)

```
<li ng-repeat="(size, stock) in sizes">
    <span ng-repeat="(key, item) in stock">
{{key}} : {{item}}
</span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

> ```
> <li ng-repeat="size in sizes">
>     <p ng-repeat="(key, value) in size"> {{ key }}: {{ value }}</p>
> </li>
> ```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Hly57DhAW25qLtfKPg9B?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using two ng-repeats which is rather expensive, you're better off either using a function which gets you the size value

```
$scope.getSize = function(size){
  return Object.keys(size)[0];
}
```

Or creating your custom filter

```
app.filter('getSize', function(){
  return function(data){
    return Object.keys(data)[0];
  }
})
```

Here is an example of using them both [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ExT9W5wLsfteEWd9Cj0w?p=preview)